# Trying to centre a radio player box using dive in wordpress - I have the code but it is permanently left aligned

Tags: html, wordpress

I am very new to all this and have little idea what I am doing, I have been looking for three hours now - I have a radio player (muses) and the code for my website. It has been on my site before, perfectly aligned in the centre. I have had to put it back on the site today and I cannot get it to sit in the centre. I have tried using div (which is all new to me) and the center commands with the right /switches at the end. I have copied and pasted and read and watched videos and none of the suggestions or solutions are working. Please can someone help me? It cannot be that hard? Am I putting something in the wrong place? The actual player works correctly - it is the location on the page that is wrong. Thank you in advance and I hope this is not stupid.

`

```
<div style="width:800px; margin:0 auto;">
<!-- BEGINS: AUTO-GENERATED MUSES RADIO PLAYER CODE -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://hosted.muses.org/mrp.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
MRP.insert({
'url':'https://reclaimedradio.radioca.st/;',
'codec':'mp3',
'volume':70,
'autoplay':false,
'jsevents':true,
'buffering':0,
'title':'Reclaimed Radio',
'wmode':'transparent',
'skin':'radiovoz',
'width':220,
'height':69
});
</script>
<!-- ENDS: AUTO-GENERATED MUSES RADIO PLAYER CODE -->
</div>`
```

Comment: Please provide enough code to meet the [minimum requirements](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so we can help. It is not possible to determine what the problem is if we cannot see the html and css in this example.

Comment: I don't understand? I just have a standard wordpress website so I don't understand what code I need to show?

Comment: Show the html and css that involves the attempt to center the player.

Comment: I thought I had in the code box above? I’m genuinely confused? Where I’d put the div bit before the section where it started listening the player parameters <div style="width:800px; margin:0 auto;">